# In my Pycharm why the df.plot() do not show up in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I have the below pandas code, I want to plot() to display the image, but PyCharm do not shows up.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


date1 = pd.date_range('20190114', periods=6)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4))  # shape(6, 4)
print(df[0])

df[0].plot()
```

In my Pycharm why the df.plot() do not show up?

[image]

Comment: use [plt.show()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you want but there you go:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

date1 = pd.date_range('20190114', periods=6)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4))  # shape(6, 4)
print(df)

plt.plot(df)
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

date1 = pd.date_range('20190114', periods=6)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 4))  # shape(6, 4)
print(df[0])

df[0].plot()
plt.show()
```